# JavaFX 11 TableView Cell navigation by TAB key pressed without custom editableCell class

Tags: javafx, tabs, navigation, tableview, focus

**The problem:**

I want to navigate through a TableView from one cell to the next right neighbor cell in JavaFX by using the TAB key.

Notice: The TableView is set to editable. And CellSelection is enabled too.

```
 tableReceipt.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

The handling of the KeyPressedEvent seemingly is not my problem, but to request the focus of the single cell on the right of the current cell.

I can focus one cell but when i press the TAB key the focus goes out of the table on other form elements.

The TableView contains some editable TextFieldTableCells and one editable ComboBoxTableCell.

I don't use a custom class for the editable Cells but Code like this:

```
Callback<TableColumn<Receipt, int>, TableCell<Receipt, int>> tfCallBack = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn();
columnAmount.setCellFactory(tfCallBack);
```

for a TableCell with editable TextField nature.

**My question:**

How can I implement a solution to solve my problem? A theoretical solution would help too. I allready searched for this topic but only found an example that's using a custom EditableCell class. I think there must be a solution using the callback method like I do.

**Solution approach:**

```
tableReceipt.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
        if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            tableReceipt.getFocusModel().focusRightCell();
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyCode.ENTER);
         }
     }
});
```

With this code I can get focus of the right cell next to the current one. And I need the ENTER KeyPress to enable the editable mode of the Cell. But when I press TAB on keyboard the new value is not committed. For example I press '2' the default value is '0' and after pressing TAB the value is again '0'.

**Question No.2:**

How can I combine the code above with a changeListener/onEditCommitListener, that the new value is stored in the cell after pressing TAB?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html)?

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: still don't fully understand what you are after ... could you please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate your requirement?

Comment: The SpreadsheetView seems to be usefull to solve this problem but i use Java 12 and the ControlsFX lib just supports Java untill version 9 at the moment.

Comment: Ok there is also a RC2 for Java 11 in a maven repository available for ControlsFX maybe I rollback my application to Java 11 if there should be issues with Java Version 12 and ControlsFX  but I think it should work too. I'm just trying.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful. You have to manually call it after you complete a cell edit.

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Brian Boutin on 5/14/2019
 */

class CellNav<T> {

    private final TableView<T> tableView;
    private KeyEvent lastKeyEvent;
    private TablePosition editingPosition;

    CellNav(TableView<T> tableView) {
        this.tableView = tableView;
        this.editingPosition = null;

        tableView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB || event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                editingPosition = tableView.getEditingCell();
                lastKeyEvent = event;
            }
        });

        tableView.setOnMouseReleased(e -> editingPosition = null);

        for (TableColumn col : tableView.getColumns()) {
            col.setOnEditCancel(event -> editingPosition = null);
        }
    }

    void doCellNav() {
        if (editingPosition == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (lastKeyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

            int selectIdx;
            if (lastKeyEvent.isShiftDown()) {
                selectIdx = editingPosition.getRow() - 1;
            } else {
                selectIdx = editingPosition.getRow() + 1;
            }

            if (selectIdx < 0 ) {
                selectIdx = tableView.getItems().size() - 1;

            } else if (selectIdx > tableView.getItems().size() - 1) {
                selectIdx = 0;
            }

            tableView.layout();
            tableView.scrollTo(selectIdx == 0 ? selectIdx : selectIdx - 1);
            tableView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(selectIdx);
            tableView.edit(selectIdx, editingPosition.getTableColumn());

        } else if (lastKeyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            TableColumn colToEdit = getNextColumn(!lastKeyEvent.isShiftDown(), editingPosition.getTableColumn());
            if (colToEdit != null) {
                tableView.layout();
                tableView.scrollToColumn(colToEdit);
                tableView.edit(editingPosition.getRow(), colToEdit);
            }
        }

        editingPosition = null;
    }

    boolean isNavigating() {
        return editingPosition != null;
    }

    private TableColumn getNextColumn(boolean forward, TableColumn currentCol) {
        List<TableColumn> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TableColumn col : tableView.getColumns()) {
            if (col.isEditable() && col.isVisible() && (col.getStyleClass().contains("editable-col") || col.getStyleClass().contains("result-col"))) {
                columns.add(col);
            }
        }

        if (columns.size() < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        int currentIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
            if (columns.get(i) == currentCol) {
                currentIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        int nextIndex = currentIndex;
        if (forward) {
            nextIndex++;
            if (nextIndex > columns.size() - 1) {
                nextIndex = 0;
            }
        } else {
            nextIndex--;
            if (nextIndex < 0) {
                nextIndex = columns.size() - 1;
            }
        }
        return columns.get(nextIndex);
    }
}


public class ExampleClass{
  CellNav cellNav;
  
  public ExampleClass() {
    TableView  yourTableView = new TableView();
    cellNav = new CellNav(yourTableView);

    TableColumn someCol = new TableColumn();
    someCol.setOnEditCommit(e -> {

     //perform a save of your table data here

       //pick up cell nav again
      if (cellNav.isNavigating()) {
        cellNav.doCellNav();
      }
    });
  }
}
```